# Get.changeTheme not working correctly on Android real device, iOS real device, iOS simulator and android emulator working fine

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-getx

I have scenario where user can has a choice to select a theme. There are multiple options for the user.

I am using `GetX`, and `Get.ChangeTheme` to update the app theme. The logic is working fine for iOS real device, iOS simulator and android emulator. But when i try to run the app on android real device, its not working correctly. It kind of updating some text items, but not in entirety.

This is my code.

```
await AppStorage().setUserCurrentTheme(ThemesManagement.fromJson(theme));
Get.changeTheme(ThemeCustomJSON.updateCustomTheme(ThemeController()));
```

I believe there is no issue in the logic, otherwise it should not have worked on other cases.

Is there something else i need to change on android level to make change theme work?